# Transform the dataframe in R

Tags: r

Can we transform this data as shown in expected output?

```
ColA   ColB  ColC
A        -    0
B        X    3
C        Y    4 
D        X    51
D        Y    32
```

Expected Output

```
ColA     X    Y
A        0    0
B        3    0
C        0    4 
D        51   32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short solution based on `data.table` (most recommended option if you have voluminous data)

```r
colA = c("A","B","C","D","D")
colB = c(NA,"X","Y","X","Y")
colC = c(0,3,4,51,32)

library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(colA = colA, colB = colB, colC = colC)

dt <- dcast(dt, colA ~ ..., fill = 0)
dt[,"NA" := NULL]

dt
   colA  X  Y
1:    A  0  0
2:    B  3  0
3:    C  0  4
4:    D 51 32
```

`dcast` makes your data from long to wide format.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, something like this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ColB:ColC), ~replace(., . == '-', 'X')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ColB, values_from = ColC, values_fill = list(ColC = 0))

#  ColA  X     Y    
#  <fct> <chr> <chr>
#1 A     0     0    
#2 B     3     0    
#3 C     0     4    
#4 D     51    32
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), ColB = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("-", "X", "Y"), class = "factor"), ColC = c(0L, 
3L, 4L, 51L, 32L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can.
Using `xtabs`:

```
res <- xtabs(ColC ~ ColA + ColB, dat)[,-1]
#     ColB
# ColA  X  Y
#    A  0  0
#    B  3  0
#    C  0  4
#    D 51 32
```

To get a data frame, do:

```
res <- as.data.frame(unclass(res))
res
#    X  Y
# A  0  0
# B  3  0
# C  0  4
# D 51 32
```

Or, all in one:

```
res <- as.data.frame(unclass(xtabs(ColC ~ ColA + ColB, dat)[,-1]))
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(ColA = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), ColB = c("-", 
"X", "Y", "X", "Y"), ColC = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 51L, 32L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```